# How to store BigInteger into a file as a byte?

Tags: java, byte, biginteger

How do I store the byte value of `BigInteger Ca` into a text file? Sample code:

```
BigInteger Ca = new BigInteger("0");
Ca = OC.mod(N).multiply(R);
Ca = Ca.mod(N);

File file = new File("text.txt");
// create the file
file.createNewFile();
// create a FileWriter Object
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of what do you expect in the file? How should `new BigInteger("1234")` be stored in the file? `0x12 0x34`, `0x0D 0x42`...

Comment: I'm expecting some unreadable garbage inside the text file. It's part of Chosen Ciphertext Attack, I'm trying to get the modified Ciphertext to send it to the Server in order to get back Mr.

Comment: Could you provide an example with a `BigInteger` you want to use and the result you expect to be in the file as hex dump. Because your explanation `unreadable garbage`is quite sketchy.

Answer (score 1):

```
    BigInteger Ca = new BigInteger("0");
    byte[] array = Ca.toByteArray();
    OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("text.txt");
    ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    outputStream.write(array);
    outputStream.close();
    fos.close();
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It doesn't work like that. You need to call either `outputStream.flush()` before closing `fos` or you call `outputStream.close()`.

Comment: Yes subOptimal.
Thanks

Comment: Writing an array as a Java object into an `ObjectOutputStream` deserves an explanation about why the complication, compared against simply writing the byte array directly to an `OutputStream`.

Comment: I can't check right now, but if `text.txt`is a text file, does that write text or just binary "garbage"?

Answer (score 0):

```
  File file = new File("Corrected.txt"); 
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(file); 
  FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("Correct.txt"); 
  BigInteger p = new BigInteger("0");
  while (sc.hasNextBigInteger())   
    {
        p = p.add(sc.nextBigInteger()); 
    }
    fw.write(p.toString());
    System.out.println(p); 
    fw.close();
```